# Splitting a single transaction into n rows, with one row per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to split a single transaction that spans over multiple days (as indicated by a START_DATE_TIME and END_DATE_TIME), into *n* rows, one row per day.  For example:

```
START_DATE_TIME       END_DATE_TIME          PRICE
20160101 20:00:00     20160104 04:00:00      1.999
```

should become:

```
START_DATE_TIME       END_DATE_TIME          PRICE
20160101 20:00:00     20160102 00:00:00      1.999
20160102 00:00:00     20160103 00:00:00      1.999
20160103 00:00:00     20160104 00:00:00      1.999
20160104 00:00:00     20160104 04:00:00      1.999
```

Any ideas how to do this?

I've figured it out for *n* <= 2, but beyond that my method becomes prohibitively complex. I'm using SSMS 2012.

Thanks in advance!

(please ignore the bad formatting above - my first post here, and still learning the ropes!)

Comment: What is your RDBMs? Different flavors works with different sintaxes for date type

Comment: And your sample is wrong right? The `end_date_time` should end at the same day at 23:59:59 not on the 00:00:00 because it is already the other day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jorge.  I'm on SSMS 2012, if that's what you're asking.  Also, yes, the END_DATE_TIMEs can all be at 23:59:59 of the same day, if that helps.

Comment: Use a table of numbers or a calendar table. Join your table with it to generate as many rows as you need. http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Vladimir.  One issue is that there will be multiple values of _n_ that need to be identified on-the-fly, so "as you need" is something that the query would have to identify.

Comment: Another question. Do you want only the dates on the table (start and end) or do you want days that also is not present. E.g. you have a row with start 20160101 and end 20160103 and start 20160105 and end 20160106 in this example do you want to see the day 20160104 ?

Comment: Just curious, are you looking to calculate the weighted average price?

Comment: Hi Jorge - eventually every calendar day will have at least one row (my whole dataset spans approximately 13 months), and in the current dataset, there are no gaps in time. I.e.; the START_DATE_TIME of row x+1 is the END_DATE_TIME of row x.

Comment: Hi John - yes, eventually I will aggregate multiple rows for a given day to get a time-weighted average price for the day.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a `numbers` table, you can do this quite readily.  You can construct one that is big enough for most purposes from `master.spt_values`:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select (case when n.n = 0 then t.start_date_time
             else dateadd(day, n.n, cast(t.start_date_time) as date))
        end) as start_date_time,
       (case when dateadd(day, n.n, cast(t.start_date_time as date)) > t.end_date_time
             then end_date_time
             else dateadd(day, n.n, cast(t.start_date_time as date))
        end) as end_date_time,
       price
from t join
     n
     on date_add(day, n, cast(t.start_date_time as date)) <= t.end_date_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the recursive CTE with cross join. The Case statement is used to capture the beginning timestamp and end timestamp:

```
DROP TABLE #tempData;
CREATE TABLE #tempData (START_DATE_TIME DateTime, 
                        END_DATE_TIME DateTime, Price Decimal(5,2));
INSERT #tempData(START_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME, Price)
VALUES ('2016-01-01 20:00:00', '20160104 04:00:00', 1.99);

DECLARE @start DateTime;
DECLARE @end DateTime;

SELECT @start = #tempData.START_DATE_TIME, @end = #tempData.END_DATE_TIME
FROM #tempData;

WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @start AS START_DATE_TIME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(CAST(DateAdd(Day, 1, START_DATE_TIME) As Date) As DateTime)
    FROM  dates
    WHERE START_DATE_TIME < @end - 1
)

SELECT dates.START_DATE_TIME,    
   CASE WHEN CAST(dates.START_DATE_TIME AS Date) = CAST(#tempData.END_DATE_TIME As Date)
        THEN #tempData.END_DATE_TIME
        WHEN CAST(dates.START_DATE_TIME AS Date) = CAST(#tempData.START_DATE_TIME As Date)
        THEN CAST(CAST(DateAdd(Day, 1, dates.START_DATE_TIME) As Date) As DateTime)
        ELSE DateAdd(Day, 1, dates.START_DATE_TIME)
   END AS END_DATE_TIME,    
   #tempData.Price

 FROM dates
 CROSS JOIN #tempData
;
```